# Installing lxml when Codespeak.net is down

Tags: python, lxml, easy-install, buildout

[Codespeak.net](http://www.codespeak.net) is [down](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/codespeak.net) and something, somewhere in my buildout wants to [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) [lxml](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hZfwWz3fA_AJ:codespeak.net/lxml/+lxml) from it, despite me boopstrapping with [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/), having it installed already and removing it from my buildout files.

How else can I get round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first way is to look at your buildout directory: you probably have an eggs/ subdirectory in there. Put your existing lxml egg in that directory and buildout should pick it up.

A second, slightly more permanent, way is to tell buildout to use a cache directory.  In your home dir, make a ".buildout" directory with a "default.cfg" in it:

```
[buildout]
eggs-directory = /home/reinout/.buildout/eggs
download-cache = /home/reinout/.buildout/downloads
extends-cache = /home/reinout/.buildout/configs
```

Also create those eggs/downloads/configs subdirectories. Now you can place your existing lxml egg in that eggs/ directory and buildout should pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help Reinout. I have changed my .buildout to use the download cache as you suggested. Problem was that I did not have that egg on my current, very new, dev system :(

My work around looks like this:

- I downloaded the tar from http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/.
- Removed all references to lxml from my buildout.
- Did a virtual-env of python2.4 in my target plone directory.
- Did a bootstrap.
- Changed dir to the untarred lxml files.
- Used the python that virtual-env gave me to install from the untarred files:
  eg. ~/instances/[my_instance]/bin/python setup.py install
- Then changed back to my instance dir and completed the buildout.

So far I am up and running, but hoping codespeak will come back soon so I can get the egg and do the caching thing like you suggested.